# How to make android:src value a dynamic value pulled from an API object in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.maps

I'm using Xamarin.Forms.Maps and in the Android project I want to change an image in the InfoWindow dynamically from the object it displays.

I know it has to do with the MapInfoWindow.xml file but I don't know how to change the android:src value that displays the image into a dynamic value that depends on the object's image property.

Currently it looks like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/monkey" />
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I guess that you want to [customize the info window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map-pin#customizing-the-info-window) to change image, you can customize a map pin.

Comment: Yes the thing is I don't know how to set a dynamic value instead of a file

Comment: Maybe you can try to add [Xamarin.Forms Bindable Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties) to loca image path in your custom map, please refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62712258/xamarin-forms-maps-adding-image-dynamically-to-infowindow)